# Missing \begin{document} in Latex

Tags: compiler-errors, latex, pdflatex

I get error in Latex. It happened after I write {fancy} code. With this error Latex added one more page in my document and it just say

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{\centering}

\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{Economic Inequality in Turkey}}
\date{December 2014}
\pagebreak

text are here

\end{document}
```

Some of Errors are:

> Undefined control sequence. \  ->\let \reserved@e 
>                          \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserv... l.10 
>         The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., '\hobx'),
>   type 'I' and the correct spelling (e.g., 'I\hbox'). Otherwise just
>   continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> Paragraph ended before \reserved@b was complete.  
>                      \par  l.10
>
> Undefined control sequence. \@fileswith@pti@ns ...served@b \reserved@a
>   ,\@nil 
>                                                     ,}\fi \reserved@a  l.10
>
> LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the (second) backslash in \usepackage{\centering} is a typo, try removing it.